# jquery text field cannot hide()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hide

I got table like this.

```
<input type=checkbox onclick=enableEdit(this)/>

<tr>
  <td onclick=enableInput(this)>
   <input style="display:none">
   <span>text1</span>
  </td>
  <td onclick=enableInput(this)>
   <input style="display:none">
   <span>text2</span>
  </td>
  <td>
   <img class='iconPlus' onclick=disableInput(this)/>
  </td>
</tr>

function enableInput(t){
$(t).closest('tr').find('input').show()
$(t).closest('tr').find('span').hide()
}

function disableInput(t){
$(t).closest('tr').find('span').show()
$(t).closest('tr').find('input').hide()
}

function enableEdit(elm){
if($(elm).is(':checked'){
  $('.iconPlus').removeAttr('onclick')
  $('td').removeAttr('onclick')
}else{
  $('.iconPlus').attr('onclick', 'disableInput(this)') 
$('td').attr('onclick','enableInput(this)')   
}    }
```

So, before I check the checkbox, I click to each `td` and it shows `input`, hides `span`. then I click `img`, it hides `input` and show `span`. It works fine.

However, When I check the check box to disable input and uncheck it. I cannot hide the `input` and show the `span` when I click on td.

I check the console, in `input`, it shows `display:inline-block` instead of `none`.
Hope you understand my situation.
Please take a look. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check the checkbox while enable or disable your elements like,

```
function enableInput(t){
   if(!$('#chk:checked').length){
      $(t).closest('tr').find('input').show()
      $(t).closest('tr').find('span').hide()
   }
}

function disableInput(t){
   if(!$('#chk:checked').length){
      $(t).closest('tr').find('span').show()
      $(t).closest('tr').find('input').hide()
   }
}
```

Add an id to your checkbox `chk` like,

```
<input id="chk" type="checkbox" onclick="enableEdit(this)"/>
```

Also, your code can be shorten as,

```
function enableInput(t){
   if(!$('#chk:checked').length){
      $(t).closest('tr').find('input,span').toggle();
   }
}
```

Alternative, Try the below code snippet,

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('.iconPlus').on('click', function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      disableInput(this);
    });
    $('td').on('click', function() {
      enableInput(this);
    });
    $(':checkbox').on('click', function() {
      enableEdit(this);
    });
  });

  function enableInput(t) {
    $(t).closest('tr').find('input').show()
    $(t).closest('tr').find('span').hide()
  }

  function disableInput(t) {
    $(t).closest('tr').find('span').show()
    $(t).closest('tr').find('input').hide()
  }


  function enableEdit(elm) {
    if ($(elm).is(':checked')) {
      $('.iconPlus,td').off('click')
    } else {
      $('.iconPlus').on('click', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        disableInput(this);
      });
      $('td').on('click', function() {
        enableInput(this);
      });
    }
  }
</script>
<input type="checkbox" />
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input style="display:none">
      <span>text1</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input style="display:none">
      <span>text2</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <img class='iconPlus' alt="img" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <input type=checkbox id="check" /><br/>
<table>
<tr>
  <td id="first" onclick=enableInput(this)>
   <input type="textbox" style="display:none">
   <span>text1</span>
  </td>
  <td id="second" onclick=enableInput(this)>
   <input type="textbox" style="display:none">
   <span>text2</span>
  </td>
  <td>
   <img class='iconPlus' onclick=disableInput(this)/>
  </td>
</tr>
      </table>
```

Jquery:

```
$('#first').click(function(){
    if($("#check").is(':checked'))
       {
       $(this).find('span').hide();
       $(this).find('input').show();
       }
});
$('#second').click(function(){
    if($("#check").is(":checked"))
       {
       $(this).find('span').hide();
       $(this).find('input').show();
}
});
```

Comment: Sir, off('click') means attr onclick being removed, you need to add on('click') and function. I tried but it's not work.

Comment: Instead of onclick function inside element add click event of jquery outside